# Vaadin layout using CSS flex-box?

Tags: flexbox, vaadin, vaadin8, vaadin10

Is there a `Layout` in [Vaadin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaadin) 8 ([*Vaadin Framework*](https://vaadin.com/framework)) or Vaadin 10 ([*Vaadin Flow*](https://vaadin.com/blog/vaadin-flow-the-next-piece-of-vaadin-10-is-now-in-developer-preview)) that uses the newer [CSS flex-box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_flex-box_layout) (a.k.a. flexbox) feature?

[This excellent tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) makes it look like flex-box could be used to implement Vaadin’s `GridLayout`, `VerticalLayout`, and `HorizontalLayout`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Vaadin 8

If you want to use flex-box in Vaadin 8, there are following options

1. If you prefer server side java API, there is add-on in directory https://vaadin.com/directory/component/flexlayout-add-on that has that.
2. You can always use CssLayout, and define CSS flex-box rules in your theme
3. The Board (https://vaadin.com/directory/component/vaadin-board) component is implemented using flex-box

## Vaadin 10 (Flow)

All Layouts in Flow are implemented using Flex-box, making them function better together. There is also a FlexLayout in Flow, that gives Java API of flex-box in similar fashion than the add-on mentioned above. HorizontalLayout and VerticalLayout are special cases flex-box, so there is less side effects when combining these (see: https://vaadin.com/docs/v10/flow/components/tutorial-flow-components-setup.html).